# Derive implicit method from Butcher tableau

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

\begin{align*}
    \begin{array}{c|cc}
         0 &0 &0  \\
         1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
         \hline
         & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
    \end{array} 
\end{align*}

How is the trapezoidal method derived from the implicit RK tableau above?

For implicit RK methods, I have that:
\begin{align}
    k_j &= y_n + h \sum_{i=1}^s a_{ji}f(t_n + c_ih,k_i) & k=j,...,s\\
    y_{n+1} &= y_n +h \sum_{j=1}^s b_j f(t_n + c_jh, k_j)\\
\end{align}
So that from the tableau:
\begin{align}
    k_1 &= y_n \\
    k_2 &= y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left ( f(t_n, k_1) + f(t_n +h, k_2) \right) \\
    &= y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left ( f(t_n, y_n) + f(t_n +h, k_2) \right) \\
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{equation}
    y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left (f(t_n,y_n) + f \left ( t_n + h,  y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left ( f(t_n, y_n) + f(t_n +h, k_2 )\right) \right ) \right ) \tag{1} \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
How do I go from the equation in \eqref{eq:1} to derive the form below?:
\begin{align}
    y_{n+1} &= y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left ( f(t_n,y_n) + f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \right )
\end{align}
Specifically, how do I remove the $k_2$ in (\ref{eq:1})?

By visual inspection, I can observe that what $k_2$ brought into the inner $f$ is equivalent to $y_{n+1}$ as formulated in \eqref{eq:1}:
\begin{equation}
    y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left (f(t_n,y_n) + f \left ( t_n + h,  \underbrace{y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left ( f(t_n, y_n) + f(t_n +h, k_2 )\right)}_{y_{n+1}} \right ) \right ) \tag{2} \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}

But how is this obtained through algebraic manipulations?

Comment: isn't (2) the same as your equation under (1), $t_n+h=t_{n+1}$.

Comment: This is perhaps too "on the nose". Try the same with the implicit midpoint method. Your development of the last step goes in the wrong direction, you should reduce it to $y_{n+1}=k_2$. But  this is only the trapezoidal method. In, e.g., the Gauss 2 method, there is a non-trivial assembly in the last step.

Comment: Interesting explanations [here](https://idontgetoutmuch.wordpress.com/2018/03/04/implicit-runge-kutta-and-gnu-scientific-library/)